# Translate: 荒谬时代要吃得好玩到老经常想母猫

Tags: translation

What's the meaning of this sentence?

荒谬时代要吃得好玩到老经常想母猫。

荒谬时代 means ridiculous age, i think. 
好玩 means amusing, fun

But i couldn't understand the whole sentence.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In the ridiculous age, (you should) eat well, be playful for the whole lifetime, and always think of the female cat.

Comment: BTW the sentence by itself sounds neutral but in the original context (the lyrics where it came from) it was definitely derogatory.

Comment: Had better mention it's from lyrics.

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the lyrics of "浅蓝大肥猫":

"你活在这样荒谬的时代里 人格通通不要
只要吃得好 玩到老 想母猫 死得早"

I'm not sure if it's proper to translate the last words.

你活在这样荒谬的时代里 = You live in such a ridiculous era;

人格通通不要 = Abandon all your personalities*;

只要吃得好 玩到老 = As long as I can eat well and play until old (or say enjoy my life);

*: Per @NS.X. 's advice, "人格" can be translate into personality and characteristic, and might be integrity in this context. Read more about "人格" at: https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA%E6%A0%BC

Comment: I think 人格 in this sentence refers to 'integrity' instead of 'personality'.

Comment: @NS.X. I think personality or character is ok here. Like 人格败坏 can be translated into personality deterioration.

Comment: I know that. I just want to make sure the Chinese language learners who read this answer are not confused between personality as 人格 vs. personality as 个性.

Comment: @NS.X. Updated more into about 人格.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, it might come from the lyrics but it is not completely the same as the original lyrics.

The lyrics of 浅蓝大肥猫 is

> 你活在这样荒谬的城市里 规矩通通不要
>   只要吃得饱 睡得好 想母猫 做春梦

which has similar meaning as the sentence in the question.

Speaking of the sentence in the question, 好玩 is not the word here. It should be 吃得好 and 玩到老, which means eat well and play until old respectively.

As for the rest, 荒谬时代 means ridiculous era, 要 means "should", 经常 means often and 想母猫　literally means "think of female cats". Therefore the whole sentence becomes "In such a ridiculous era, we should eat well, play until we are old(enjoy life) and spend time thinking of female cats.